# Can not add new site - WPMU

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I installed WPMU on hostgator, everything is fine except I can not add new site in wp-admin/network/sites.php

I installed the fresh WP4.2.2 with default WP theme, no plugins activated.

I faced this errors

> Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given
>   in /home1/xxx/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 3435
>
> Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given
>   in /home1/xxx/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 3424
>
> Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given
>   in /home1/xxx/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 3435
>
> Warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
>   in /home1/xxx/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 3407
>
> Warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
>   in /home1/xxx/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 3407
>
> Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted
>   to string in /home1/xxx/public_html/wp-includes/kses.php on line 1038

The screen is dead at this.

I contacted with hostgator support staff but they can't solve the problem.

Can someone give me a suggestion please?

I really need to get the site works properly.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a know issue, with a fix underway:
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32308#comment:4